# Type check failure on missing optional in Flow

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, flowtype

Say I have a Flow typedef like this:

```
type ApiResponse = {
  +foo?: { [string]: Object },
  +bar?: { [string]: Object},
}

type FooApiResponse = {
  foo: { [string] : Object }
}
```

And a functions with the following signature:

```
function does_not_accept(baz : ApiResponse) : void  {
  if(baz.foo) { console.log(baz.foo) }
}

function also_does_not_accept(baz: $Shape<ApiResponse>) : void {
  if(baz.foo) { console.log(baz.foo) }
}
```

Calling either one of these function with a `FooApiResponse` in the argument position fails.

The first one fails with a missing attribute error for `bar` (even though it's optional.)

The second one fails because `bar` is read only (even though it's never written to.)

How do I write a function that accepts these sorts of various "subtypes" of `ApiResponse`

An argument type signature like `$Supertype<ApiRsponse>` works - but I don't understand why.  How is the sub/super relationship resolved between `FooApiResponse` and `ApiResponse`?  What is this problem called?  I don't really even know the vocabulary to google for an answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

`$Shape` and `$Supertype` are experimental features.  If they are not doing what you want, or hope they should do, consider opening an issue.

`ApiResponse` has no super type, other than Object.  It probably works because you are stripping off the defined properties - same as using `{}`.  I suspect its intended to be used with class types that use `extends`.

If you type an object literal specifically as `FooApiResponse`, then you'd expect it not to be acceptable as an `ApiResponse` even if they had the same shape.  You need an intersection on the argument type to allow it to accept either.

```
function accept(baz: ApiResponse | FooApiResponse) {}
```

I think the Flow errors that are shown are unhelpful, so maybe open an issue for that.  The `+` to indicate Read Only also seems to obfuscate the errors, but you've not used it in the `FooApiResponse` definition so the types are not compatible with regards to `foo`.